# Setting Vimeo thumbnail inside imageMapster toolTip,

Tags: jquery, tooltip, thumbnails, vimeo, imagemapster

I am having problem on getting just one thumbnail on mouse over inside an imageMapster toolTip map.
Actually my code keeps putting several thumbnails repeating them on every mouseover.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/H3mRE/1/

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element. But when `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

use  `html()` instead of `append()`  like

```
$('.toolTIPbocadillo').html(thumbImg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H3mRE/2/

hope this will help

Comment: Thank you!. However, I was expecting to show each thumbnail from each vimeo link and this even get me more confuse. What does it prevent from getting rigth thumbnail from hover mouse at each position link?

Comment: I am experiencing a slight time delay for changing the thumbnail image. Hope you want the 'LABCC' image as first thumbnail and image of man as second thumbnail. right?

Comment: Yes, right. I was trying to set one different thumbnail for each area defined by vimeoref tag, because I am planing to use href for another click action. But it does not behave as expected.